# Where is the code that sends an email when an account is being activated in the backend?

Tags: email, customer-account

I'm working on shop where the customers will be imported by CSV, new customers will have NO password (password_hash = "").

The administrator will have to activate the new customers using the backend.

If a customer becomes activated, a random password should be generated and it should be included in the mail.

What I need to know is just where I find the code where the email will be sent.
The code of the email template is "customer_create_account_email_template".

It's not the `sendNewAccountEmail()` method in `app/code/core/Customer/Model/Customer.php` and it's not either `successProcessRegistration()` in `app/code/core/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't specify a Magento version so I'll explain it based on the current version CE 1.9.1.0. If you are sure that `sendNewAccountEmail()` isn't used I'd suggest you have a look at `sendPasswordReminderEmail()` in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php`.

Here is an explanation:

- When you submit the customer submit form, the method `Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController::saveAction()` is triggered.
- The password and e-mail logic starts in the code block around line 305:

  ```
  $isNewCustomer = $customer->isObjectNew();
  try {
      $sendPassToEmail = false;
      // Force new customer confirmation
      if ($isNewCustomer) {
          $customer->setPassword($data['account']['password']);
          $customer->setForceConfirmed(true);
          if ($customer->getPassword() == 'auto') {
              $sendPassToEmail = true;
              $customer->setPassword($customer->generatePassword());
          }
      }
      Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_customer_prepare_save', array(
          'customer'  => $customer,
          'request'   => $this->getRequest()
      ));

      $customer->save();
      // ...
  } // ...
  ```

  Here, the password for a new customer would be generated.
- Next, the mails are sent:

  ```
  // Send welcome email
  if ($customer->getWebsiteId() && (isset($data['account']['sendemail']) || $sendPassToEmail)) {
      $storeId = $customer->getSendemailStoreId();
      if ($isNewCustomer) {
          $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('registered', '', $storeId);
      } elseif ((!$customer->getConfirmation())) {
          // Confirm not confirmed customer
          $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('confirmed', '', $storeId);
      }
  }
  if (!empty($data['account']['new_password'])) {
      $newPassword = $data['account']['new_password'];
      if ($newPassword == 'auto') {
          $newPassword = $customer->generatePassword();
      }
      $customer->changePassword($newPassword);
      $customer->sendPasswordReminderEmail();
  }
  ```

  Normally, the mail template `customer_create_account_email_template` is used when a new user registered and confirmation is not required (i.e. `$customer->sendNewAccountEmail('registered', '', $storeId);` in the snippet above).

  As you imported the customer before and just re-save it with a auto-generated password, the second part of the code should apply and the mail should be sent here:

  ```
  $customer->changePassword($newPassword);
  $customer->sendPasswordReminderEmail();
  ```

  This method `sendPasswordReminderEmail()` which can be found in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php` uses the mail template configured as the "Remind E-Mail Template".

Comment: Thank you for answer.
Well, I discovered that the code was in an extension for custom customer attributes, which overrides several methods, include the mail functions.

And, I've been writing a csv importer which directly import into the database without using any magento classes, because I've been under time pressure to get an importer finished, which is runnable by a cron job. In the import, I just leave the password_hash empty, so it has to be generated first.

I think it would have been better and easier to write the importer as a n98-magerun module.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It would be best then if you add this as an answer yourself and accept it (= click the check mark next to the answer). This is perfectly fine and every accepted answer helps to get our site out of Beta!