# Magento customer import email sending

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer, import

I have a CSV files with customer data, i like to send a email notification to the user once the account is created.
    So i like to know,in Magento(1.9) core have any email notification functionality for import user(for account creation)?

Comment: visit question:-http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54952/where-is-the-code-that-sends-an-email-when-an-account-is-being-activated-in-the

Comment: I have read your previous answer,but the answer is not closely match with my expect answer.My question is,in magento customer import have any email functionality or not. In your previous post answer is related to the form submission email functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send emails with Magento you need to configure it to use an **SMTP server**.

Remember anyway that if you set a **normal SMTP server on Magento** – like the ones associated to Gmail or Hotmail – you could always run into deliverability problems. Only a [professional SMTP service](https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension) will guarantee a full delivery rate, so if you plan to set up an email campaign you should consider this option seriously.

You can set the SMTP host and port in *System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings*.

For sending emails from an external SMTP server however I would recommend the free extension [SMTP Pro (on Github)](https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension).